# Не добавляется проект(Тестовый проект NUnit) в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

В Microsoft Visual 2022 При создании проекта (Тестовый проект NUnit)не добавляется проект в решение. В чем может быть причина?
В Фолдере Решение “Project” (проекты:0)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]